# How to parse object id from object

Tags: java, node.js, mongoose, morphia, objectid

I have two type of projects, Java and Node js

The java project returns the details with ObjectId

```
{
        "timestamp": 1491806328,
        "machineIdentifier": 9737042,
        "processIdentifier": 6393,
        "counter": 1399563,
        "date": 1491806328000,
        "time": 1491806328000,
        "timeSecond": 1491806328
    }
```

In node Js I am using the Mongoose. Now I dont know how to parse this to nodejs equalant ObjectId.

Edit :

Code I tried,

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var idToParse = {
            "timestamp": 1491806328,
            "machineIdentifier": 9737042,
            "processIdentifier": 6393,
            "counter": 1399563,
            "date": 1491806328000,
            "time": 1491806328000,
            "timeSecond": 1491806328
        };

    mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(idToParse);
```

it returns Undefined.

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried with? :-)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Mr, @AustinKootz thank you for the advice. Now edited the code. Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer for this.

```
function hex(length, n) {
 n = n.toString(16);
 return (n.length===length)? n : "00000000".substring(n.length, length) + n;
}

var idToParse = {
            "timestamp": 1491806328,
            "machineIdentifier": 9737042,
            "processIdentifier": 6393,
            "counter": 1399563,
            "date": 1491806328000,
            "time": 1491806328000,
            "timeSecond": 1491806328
        };


var idString = hex(8,idToParse.timestamp)+hex(6,idToParse.machineIdentifier)+hex(4,idToParse.processIdentifier)+hex(6,idToParse.counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java , try to make use of Jackson to map POJO to json and have a custom serializer for Object Id field so that Jackson understands that it needs to give String equivalent of ObjectId.
Custom serializer will look like this :

```
public class ObjectIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ObjectId>{
   @Override
   public void serialize(ObjectId id, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    if(id == null){
        jgen.writeNull();
    }else{
        jgen.writeString(id.toString());
    }
}}
```

and you can annotate ObjectId field in POJO like :
    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId id;

Comment: Thankyou . @Vaishnavi, Unfortunately the Java part is a external party. So i have to do the javascript generation. finally I got the code. thank you